# Disable DTD in javax XML Validator

Tags: java, xml, security, xml-validation, owasp

I am using [javax.xml.validation.Validator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html) to validate my xml as below -

```
        Validator validator = myschema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
```

I would like to prevent XML External Entity attacks by disabling DTDs (Document Type Definitions) completely, so I'd like for the validator to throw an exception in case of a DTD in my xml if possible. I have read about doing this using `DocumentBuilderFactory`. How do i do configure this in Validator?

Comment: So as to not throw out the quality for security. You can use [**XML catalogs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog) for local (checked) copies of DTD files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [OWASP XXE prevention spreadsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Java) for Java, the following should work:

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
Schema myschema = factory.newSchema();
Validator validator = myschema.newValidator();
try {
  validator.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
  validator.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
  validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
} catch ...
```

Refer to the [`XMLConstants` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html) for more details.

Comment: This is not working currently. We get this exception 

Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.

Comment: @GaneshBhat - you might want to open a new SA question, posting details of your setup including Java version, XML provider vendor and version, etc. Feel free to link here if you do.

Comment: This is not working for me as now I get a SAXParseException because the validator is unable to access the external because of **that** option. Actually the question title suggests about completely disabling the dtd, while the text on the contrary refers explicitly to the remote retrieval of xml resources

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ, well the text also specifies "disabling DTDs [...] completely" too. In your case, did you provide a scheme that matched where your DTDs are, e.g. `jar:file` if they were in a local JAR, for the `ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD` option?

Comment: Well, I did not. I just wanted to disable DTD validation completely. You may ask what is the purpose of that... Well, I have an official XSD that is equivalent to the DTD and I provided it to my validator. But the validator, once detecting the presence of the DTD declaration in the **body** of the XML, requires the DTD to be loaded. Terrific. Maybe I just wanted to validate the document against the correct XML integrity *at this stage* and perform additional checks later. That is the point of my comment. Yes, I see that "completely" is part of the question text and I do apologize now for that.

Answer (score -1):

This would also work-

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);

Schema myschema = factory.newSchema();

Validator validator = myschema.newValidator();

validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
```